# Data not showing on screen when api response has the data and I have subscribed, Angular 6

Tags: angular, angular6

I have a web api where I am getting a list of account numbers.

c#

```
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetAccountNumber(string username)
    {
        var accountNumber = await (
            from ca
            select new { ca.account_number }).ToListAsync();


        // Return the records
        return Json(accountNumber);
    }
```

I am using angular 6 to display data.
html

typescript component

```
`accountnumbers:AccountNumbers = {
account_number:    null
```

}`

```
ngOnInit() {
var currentUser = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('currentUser'));
this.sub = this.aroute.params.subscribe(params => {
  if(currentUser.username != null) {
    let apiURL = this.systemSettings.getWebAPISettings('accountNumber');
    let token = this.userService.getToken();
    // Setup the header with the auth token
    let headers = new Headers({ 
      'Authorization': 'Bearer ' + token
    });
    let urlOptions = new RequestOptions({ headers: headers, params: {
      "username": currentUser.username
    }});

    this.http.get(apiURL, urlOptions).subscribe(res => {
      this.accountnumbers = res.json();
    });
  }
});
```

response in chrome

[{"account_number":"90001931"}]

The account number is not showing on the screen. What have I done wrong?

Answer (score 0):

It's a race condition: when the template first loads, this.accountnumbers is still undefined. Then, once the API call finishes,  Observable resolves and a value is assigned, a change detection cycle is triggered, and then you see the values.

There are two typical patterns to fix this:

Use the [elvis operator](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elvis_operator) (probably best in your case because you only have that one accessor):

```
<p [innerText]="accountnumbers[0]?.account_number"></p>
```

`?.` means "access the property to the right of this operator if the operand to the left is defined".

Comment: I should still be able to open a screen and have data load onto the screen for initial viewing. Why is the data not loaded? This cannot be a reactive form issue.

Comment: where is your `reactive form`, can you share the snippet?

Comment: <input matInput name="account_number" [(ngModel)]="accountnumbers.account_number" #account_number="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="Account Number" readonly>

Comment: you can do this: `<input matInput name="account_number" [(ngModel)]="accountnumbers[0].account_number" #account_number="ngModel" type="text" placeholder="Account Number" readonly>`

Comment: you can check it here: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-unaa2n?file=app/input-overview-example.html

Comment: Thanks, and if i have more than one?  There are going to be more than one account number and then based on those there will be more than one contract number but all based on username.

Comment: if you have mor ethan you can always use `*ngFor` but make sure the model applies to one input only, if you have multiple inputs you can attach multiple models to it

Comment: i get a "Cannot read property 'account_number' of undefined error. and the *ngFor is not liking anything i do. do you know why?

Comment: That means `account_number` is not defined in your component.

Comment: defined as so contractnumbers:ContractNumbers[] = [];